# Best way to use dynamic SQL with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Currently I'm using RQL (https://github.com/persvr/rql) as rest query language. Previously, Query DSL was used with the meta model for the SQL queries.

It is very easy to navigate over the metamodel to create a Predicate.
It is enough to use the root entity and was able to work your way through all the relationships and find out the Predicate

Example:

```
class Foo{
  private Set<Bar> bars
}

class Bar{
  private String name;
}
```

rql: `filter=eq(bars.name, "test)`

Query DSL is: `QFoo.bars` --> SetPath and then navigate to `bars.name` is a SimpleExpression then you can call SimpleExpression.eq returns the Predicate.

Is there also this possibility with jOOQ to create the condition dynamically?

I can't find way with the statically generated fields because they don't contain any relationships, do they?

What is the best way to create the condition using the root resource? Hints?

Or can I simply create a condition from the predicate?

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.17, to-many path expressions aren't yet available, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13639

But you don't need them anyway, they're just syntax sugar for an `IN` or `EXISTS` predicate. E.g.

```java
FOO.ID.in(select(BAR.FOO_ID).from(BAR).where(BAR.NAME.eq("test")))
```

It's a bit more verbose, but straightforward, I think? Note that [every jOOQ query is a dynamic SQL query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/). You're not required to write the predicate like this. You can compose it from its individual parts completely dynamically.

Comment: So far it is clear to me, but do I have a chance (via reflection?) of dynamically from bars.name to get this jOOQ statement. It seems kind of difficult to really find generic rules for every statement.


In QueryDSL it's pretty easy because the path just reflects the Java attribute names as well. It's probably a coincidence, but that makes it very easy at the moment. In jOOQ you need more information or I don't have the idea.

Comment: @MelleD: Well, let's start by what `eq(bars.name, "test")` means here, or what it *should* mean. `bars.name` isn't a simple expression. It can imply one of two things: 1) `bars` is semi-joined to `foo` (as what I've shown in explicit SQL). This seems to be an incorrect default implementation for this path expression type, 2) `bars` is left joined to `foo` (what will be done with https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13639, though you'll have to make the relationship explicit in `FROM`, too). This convenience is hiding a lot of query logic complexity from you, maybe even producing wrong queries?

Comment: @MelleD: So, long story short, I'm not convinced that the premise you came to jOOQ with is correct. An `eq(bars.name, "test")` expression seems convenient, but it raises questions as well. Either, it is implemented weirdly (1) or you're not getting the right result (2). Better think about this a bit more thoroughly, and with a more specific question about how to do something more specific with jOOQ, I can then maybe answer that as well.

Comment: Hey Lukas, sorry for late response:
Currently there is no question which SQL will be produced. In our current implementation (IN statement is actually used), but the question is more about how to find out a metamodel level, if there is a path relationship between foo and bars. This information does not currently exist in the generated meta model, right?

So short story:
The meta model is currently being read out like:
1. Is there an attribute bars for foo
2. What type of relationship is it
3. Is there an attribute name for bar.

Comment: @MelleD: that sounds like a different question? Hard to answer in the comments. Why not ask a new, specific question?

Comment: Why is it different? I think my issue is, it is not possible --> https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13639

Currently with query dsl i have the chance to know with bars.name and the root entity foo. That foo.bars is a SetPath and bars.name is a single value and then i can dynamically build the Predicate and SQL. See no chance how to this with jOOQ with this informations

Comment: @MelleD: I find it hard to answer questions in the comments (it takes a lot of time, and I answer a lot of questions). Yours was about writing a *specific* query. Your comment seems to be about  meta data navigation. It seems quite different in terms of what the *question* is about. Of course, you're still thinking about the same problem, but that doesn't mean the questions are the same. Think in terms of a future visitor of this question. Are they going to profit from reading through lengthy comment discussions? Probably not. Here's a few more hints: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're right, it's also hard to make the situation clear in comments. Maybe a conversation would be the better way anyway.

In my view, both things are related.

I do not want to write ONE specific query but a dynamic one that can change depending on the RQL content, i.e. I need both dynamic metadata navigation. That is the prerequisite for later being able to build the SQL query from the metadata. Unless you know a better way?

Should I rephrase the question?